# How to save and reuse Eclipse settings?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I create a new workspace for every three days. Every time, I have to reset all my setting. It is taking much time, and if I make any mistakes, it takes much time to realize.

I want to save:

1. Window-> Preferences(Java, Grails, Groovy..) settings
2. My Personal Perspectives
3. Run/External Configurations

My idea is I kept all the settings files in some common project, I will import that project, after every new workspace created. Then all the settings need to come and then I will check-out all my projects.

Comment: I keep them in different folders ;d

Answer (score 2):

Settings for 1 and 2 are stored in /.metadata. Copy that to your new workspace and all the settings will be moved.
For number 3, Run configurations are project specific and stored in the root folder of each project. they have a .launch extension.
Perhaps a batch process could move them for you.

Answer (score 0):

For some of these settings (e.g. Java Compiler Preferences), you can Export and Import Preferences.